# Unity3d C# XmlSerializer Stops Partialy Behind Creating Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xmlserializer

I have a strange problem with the `XmlSerializer` in `Unity3d`.
It just stops the executions of random functions:

### Code:

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
  myClimate = (Climate)int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute ("Climate"));
  reader.ReadToFollowing ("fertilities");
  List<int> ferIDs = new List<int>();
  while (reader.Read ()) {
    if (reader.IsStartElement ("fertility")) {
      ferIDs.Add (int.Parse (reader.GetAttribute ("ID")));
    }
    if(reader.Name == "fertilities"){
      break;
    }
  }
  foreach (int item in ferIDs) {
    myFertilities.Add (World.current.getFertility(item)); 
  }
  myCities = new List<City> ();
  wilderniss = null;
  reader.ReadToFollowing ("Cities");

  if (reader.ReadToDescendant ("City")) {
    do {
      Debug.Log ("City"); 
      //works till here 
      Debug.Log ("WTF?"); 
      City c = new City (this.myTiles,this);

      //but its stops here
      Debug.Log ("oh? ");//does not get called
      this.wilderniss = c;//does not get called
      Debug.Log ("OHO? spagettio");// does not get called
      c.ReadXml (reader);//Gets called
      myCities.Add (c);//gets also called


    } while(reader.ReadToNextSibling ("City"));
  }
}
```

Why are some of the funtions get called and some not?
How does that even happen, because almost the same code works just fine in other classes of my Programm?

Comment: i think i kinda found the reason why it stopped? 
But not why its partialy stopped. The reason was an foreach loop that was assign the class(city) to a tile... I dont know why this would cause an bug when created there,but not anywhere else? Does anyone know why? or how to fix it?

Comment: Try wrapping it in a try catch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its still didnt work... i just moved the foreach out of the constructor and its working now...